# Who is the narrator in the movie Book Thief?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-book-thief

I have just saw the movie and I have some doubts about the narrator's identity.

- In the first part of the movie it made me suspect that he is Liesel's brother (I think there was a line were he mentions he was alive once)
- When Max came into picture I gained the impression that the narrator is his father
- An in the end, before the bombing it appears to be Death

I can't say for certain who it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And now that I've searched a bit on [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816442/)
I saw at at Cast the answer:

**Roger Allam   ... 
Narrator / Death (voice)**

Comment: I don't know if such a little casting credit really is a sufficient explanation of the whole matter. Maybe the narrator had more than one identity? But I haven't seen the movie, so this is pure speculation based on your question. I'm just saying that such an easy-out IMDb answer seems a bit "lame" to me.

Comment: For me all three possibilities seem plausible. In the end it does sound like Death but throughout the movie I had the impression that it was someone who knew them.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie but in the book, the narrator is explicitly "Death."

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, As mentioned by Dan about the narrator in the book, in the movie also narrator doesn't have multiple identities, only one - "Death".